# Porting d3-voronoi to d3-delunay

Tags: d3.js, voronoi

What I want to do is replicate a data-structure produced by processing the output from `d3-voronoi`, but by using `d3-delaunay` instead.

The data-structure in question is the one produced by this `makeMesh` function:

```js
function makeMesh(pts, extent) {
      extent = extent || defaultExtent;
      var vor = voronoi(pts, extent);
      var vxs = [];
      var vxids = {};
      var adj = [];
      var edges = [];
      var tris = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < vor.edges.length; i++) {
          var e = vor.edges[i];
          if (e == undefined) continue;
          var e0 = vxids[e[0]];
          var e1 = vxids[e[1]];
          if (e0 == undefined) {
              e0 = vxs.length;
              vxids[e[0]] = e0;
              vxs.push(e[0]);
          }
          if (e1 == undefined) {
              e1 = vxs.length;
              vxids[e[1]] = e1;
              vxs.push(e[1]);
          }
          adj[e0] = adj[e0] || [];
          adj[e0].push(e1);
          adj[e1] = adj[e1] || [];
          adj[e1].push(e0);
          edges.push([e0, e1, e.left, e.right]);
          tris[e0] = tris[e0] || [];
          if (!tris[e0].includes(e.left)) tris[e0].push(e.left);
          if (e.right && !tris[e0].includes(e.right)) tris[e0].push(e.right);
          tris[e1] = tris[e1] || [];
          if (!tris[e1].includes(e.left)) tris[e1].push(e.left);
          if (e.right && !tris[e1].includes(e.right)) tris[e1].push(e.right);
      }

      var mesh = {
          pts: pts,
          vxs: vxs,
          adj: adj,
          tris: tris,
          edges: edges,
          extent: extent
      }
      mesh.map = function (f) {
          var mapped = vxs.map(f);
          mapped.mesh = mesh;
          return mapped;
      }
      return mesh;
  }
```

I've been trying to solve this for a while now and have finally made some progress here on observablehq:

https://observablehq.com/@folcon/original-code-by-martin-oleary-mewo2

I'm assessing how well it works by comparing the rendered images:
[image: The goal image]

I want to produce these smooth colour transitions, which requires a correct mapping between vertices, heightmap and triangles.

**Attempt 1:**

[image: Succeeded in rendering something]

Well I got something rendered, if my approach below doesn't work, it might be instructive to come back to this.

**Attempt 2:**

[image: Trying to draw the edges in order]

This one I feel is a lot better, I don't appear to be getting extra triangles (no black ones visible), but the issue appears to be I'm rendering in the wrong order. I was attempting to go from the leftmost point and then walk around the cell edges, this seems like the right idea, but the ordering is wrong...

I've dug into the [delunator's guide to datastructures](https://mapbox.github.io/delaunator/) and at this point I feel like I'm pretty close, but missing something obvious.

Useful Notes / Assumptions:

1. The mesh uses the edges of the cells, not the triangles for "edges", if you look at the adj (adjacencies) it's never higher than 3, which is in keeping with using the cells as each vertex of the cell has no more than 3 neighbours.

[image: Example for 1.]

2. Given that an edge is an edge of a cell, the left and the right of the edge should therefore be the two cells that edge sits on.

[image: Example for 2.]

Hopefully that's clear.

---

To answer @thclark:

**The Output Data Structure:**

```js
{
  pts: pts,
  vxs: vxs,
  adj: adj,
  tris: tris,
  edges: edges,
  extent: extent
}
```

`pts` is the original points array, which is a list of pairs of [x, y] coordinates.
`vxs` is the vertices of the cell as pairs of [x, y] coordinates. The points here are unique, and their index in the array is the authoritative id for that vertex.

I will use one of [redblobgame's images](https://observablehq.com/@redblobgames/centroid-and-voronoi-polygons) to clarify:

[image: detailed voronoi]

The red dots in this image are the original points, the blue one's are the vertices of the cell.

`edges` is are comprised of 4 values, the first two are the indexes of the vertices that make up the edges of a cell, which in the image above are in white. The second two are the circumcenter's corresponding left and right cells which I've illustrated in an image above, but hopefully this will be clearer:

[image: clarifying the four values of an edge]

`adj` is a mapping from a vertex index to the other vertex index's which are connected to it, because we're using the cells, no entry in adj should have more than 3 indexes. As you can see in the image below, each vertex (red), can only have 3 neighbours (green).

[image: clarifying adj]

`tris` is an array of triangles, the original data-structure does not always have complete triangles, but they indexed by the vertex index, to the circumcenter's corresponding left and right cells.

[image: Clarifying tris]

You can see in the above image, that by combining the left and right circumcenter's of three edges, it describes a triangle.

**The Input Data Structure:**

Delaunator's [data-structures guide](https://mapbox.github.io/delaunator/) has a lot more detail, but a quick overview is this:

Delaunator takes an array of [x, y] coordinates of length N and makes a points array of length 2N where each coordinate in the original [x, y] array now sits at it's original index * 2 if it was the x coord, and * 2 + 1 if it was the y.

For example, the coords `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` would become: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

It then builds a delaunay triangulation, where each triangle edge is comprised of two halfedge's.

A halfedge takes a bi-directional edge and splits it into two directional edges.

So a triangle made up of 3 edges, now has 6 halfedges like so:

[image: Showing halfedges]

It also constructs two arrays:

`delaunay.triangles` which takes a halfedge index and returns the point id (an index into the points array described previously) where the halfedge begins.
`delaunay.halfedges` which takes a halfedge index and returns the opposite halfedge in the adjacent triangle:

[image: Showing opposite halfedge in the adjacent triangle]

Hopefully that's sufficient detail?

I've tried to make the setup runnable, so if someone wants to poke around with it to test out a quick hypothesis, they can do so easily, just [edit the notebook or fork it](https://observablehq.com/@folcon/original-code-by-martin-oleary-mewo2).

I've also added at the bottom a more complete example that's purely focused on the "physical" things the map derives from the mesh+heightmap, which is basically the coastline and rivers.

Comment: With the benefit of a phonecall, I asked @toofarsideways to elaborate the data structures that go in and out of what he's trying to achieve. toofarsideways, can you extend the answer to include the description of the output data structure that we talked about, which is 2D mesh description carrying additional redundant data.